# Change datatype of SSIS flat file data with string "NULL" values

Tags: ssis, data-conversion, ssis-2012, ssis-data-types

In my SSIS project I have to retrieve my data from a flat csv file. The data itself looks something like this:

> AccountType,SID,PersonID,FirstName,LastName,Email,Enabled
> NOR,0001,0001,Test,Test0001,Test1@email.com,TRUE
> NOR,1001,NULL,Test,Test1002,Test2@email.com,FALSE
> TST,1002,NULL,Test,Test1003,Test3@email.com,TRUE

I need to read this data and make sure it has the correct datatypes for future checks. Meaning SID and PersonID should have a numeric datatype, Enabled should be a boolean. But I would like to keep the same columns and names as my source file.

It seems like the only correct way to read this data trough the 'Flat File Source'-Task is as String. Otherwise I keep getting errors because "NULL" is literally a String and not a NULL value.

Next I perform a Derived Column transformation to get rid of all "NULL" values. For example, I use the following expression for PersonId:

`(TRIM(PersonID) == "" || UPPER(PersonID) == "NULL") ? (DT_WSTR,50)NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : PersonID`

I would like to immediatly convert it to the correct datatype by adding it in the expression above, but it seems impossible to select another datatype for the same column when I select 'Replace 'PersonId'' in the Derived Column dropdown box.

So next up I thought of using the Data Conversion task next to change the datatypes of these columns, but when I use this it only creates new columns, even when I enter the output alias to remain the same.

How could I alter my solution to efficiently and correctly read this data and convert its values to the correct datatypes?

Comment: `0001` when converted to a number is `1`. Do you need to preserve leading zeros? if so this is definitely a string. I suggest you do not rely on the text driver to get data types correct. Instead, import everything as string and convert it in SSIS. You cannot change the datatype of a column in the way you want, it needs to be a new column. I suggest you use a new column name with come kind of consistent identifier, i.e. `cPersonID`,`cSID`

Comment: actually you might be able to do what you want with a script transformation but it's not for the faint hearted

Comment: Here's a good example of script transformation that actually does what you want - same column different data type https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-script-component-as-transformation/

Comment: Thank you, now I know better what my possibilities are. I was asked not to use the script component too much because the data I am given could be changed in the future, making it more difficult to be rewritten. But the validation of my data's types is important so perhaps I should use the extra columns. Or would you know of a way to just keep my data in string format but check if every column _could_ be converted to a number for example?

Comment: I only ever use SSIS as a tool to get raw data into a database. Then I do all the work in the database. I suggest you import all columns as string into a staging table that has varchar columns, then use T-SQL functions like `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` to validate and convert data. Source files are unreliable. You can build all kinds of validation logic into SSIS but it becomes very complicated and impractical IMHO